# kml to encoded polyline/polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The utility at http://www2.warrensburgr6.org/boundary/encoder/#details is good for converting kml files to encoded polylines for use with the Google Maps Javascript API v2. But I notice it no longer works for polygons. So I have two questions:

1) Is there anything equivalent for the Google Maps v3 API?

2) Is it still possible to use encoded polygons with the Google Maps v2 API? If so, how?

And before anyone asks, yes I know it's possible to display kml data directly. But due to the size of the files, I don't want to do so.

Comment: Questions about software are probably better suited to [su] although asking for an alternates software recommendation is likely to be seen as opinion based and could be closed.

Comment: The [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2) was  officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. It should not be used for any new maps (it has been replaced with a wrapper for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 and could stop working at any time).

Comment: how is big the kml file?

Comment: @ Mark Fitzgerald, I'm not asking for people to recommend one piece of software over another. I'm merely asking if there's anything that does for Google Maps v3 what this utility did for Google Maps v2.

Comment: @geocodezip, I'm well aware that the v2 API has been deprecated. But it's not for you to say whether it should be used for any new maps: that depends on the purpose of the maps. I was not aware about the wrapper though. That explains a lot, and means it's unlikely to ever stop working - but presumably the encoded polygons feature never worked on the wrapper.

Comment: @scaisEdge the whole thing is 1.9MB as a kmz - I'm not sure about the unzipped size. The component kms are all different sizes, with many containing superfluous data that's not needed (such as elevation info).

Comment: Is only a kml or are several, is static or dinamic?.

Comment: @scaisEdge Static. It used to be several but I assembled them into one compound KML. However I think I'd need to split it up again for displaying on Google Maps, as I'd want various parts to appear at different times. But that's all moot now (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

Question effectively withdrawn, as I've now managed to hack the encoder utility to produce v3 code.

(I'd still be interested to know whether the v2 API wrapper can be made to display the polygons, but that's really just idle curiosity).